# pam sss authentication success pam sss account failure 4 (System error)

Tags: server, pam

I have been trying to work with this configuration for about 5 hours now, and have no idea what is going on. I made sure I checked all the permissions for another box (different flavor one is kali linux the one I am having trouble with is Ubuntu Server 16.04.1) for sssd, but it just isn't wanting to authenticate to the domain like the kali box does.

```
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME su[2339]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=local user uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/10 ruser=local user rhost=  user=domain user
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME sssd_be: message repeated 2 times: [ GSSAPI client step 1]
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 2
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME sssd_be: message repeated 2 times: [ GSSAPI client step 1]
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 2
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME su[2339]: pam_sss(su:auth): authentication success; logname=local user uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/10 ruser=local user rhost= user=domain user
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME su[2339]: pam_sss(su:account): Access denied for user domain user: 4 (System error)
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME su[2339]: pam_acct_mgmt: System error
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME su[2339]: FAILED su for domain user by local user
Oct 24 05:26:23 HOSTNAME su[2339]: - /dev/pts/10 local user:domain user
```

Please let me know of any other log files you need, because I have no idea what to do.